# How to change x-axis labels in plot generated by Groupby

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I want to replace the current x-axis label to the label shown below:
labels = ["Oct","Nov","Dec", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July"]

The code I've used to generate the plot is:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1M')).sum().plot.bar(legend=False)
```

The output that I got is shown below, here you can see the x-axis have label as dates.

[image]

How I can replace those labels with Month names?

Answer (score 1):

First generate your *groupby* result:

```
tbl = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M')).sum()
```

Then change the index from "full" dates into abbreviated month names:

```
tbl.set_index(tbl.index.month_name().rename('Month').map(lambda tt: tt[:3]), inplace=True)
```

And finally draw your figure:

```
tbl.plot.bar(legend=False);
```

Note the trailing `;` to prevent from additional display concerning
the type of the created object.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Date formatters](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/dates_api.html#date-formatters). There exists [DateFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) class which accepts a `fmt` argument which is a [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) format string.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) is a reference of `strftime()` and `strptime()` format codes.

To format as month abbreviated name, you need to use `%b`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='1M')).sum().plot.bar(legend=False)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(fmt='%b'))

plt.show()
```

Comment: how does ax related to plt?

Comment: @MaxHodges The return type of [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) is matplotlib.axes.Axes, which is the fundamental element of matplotlib.